# Malloc changing another variable's value (char*)

Tags: c, memory, malloc

So I'm using the following code, where the function calls looks like this (note the string literal) :

```
rmv_zeros("288230376151711744000000", '0', '-');
```

Here is the code:

```
char *rmv_zeros(char *result, char base_0, char minus) {
    char *formatted;

    formatted = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(result) + 1));
    if (result[0] == base_0 || (result[1] == base_0 && result[0] == minus)) {
        if (if_rmv_zeros_needed(result, formatted, base_0, minus) == char_to_str(base_0)) {
            return char_to_str(base_0);
        } else {
            return if_rmv_zeros_needed(result, formatted, base_0, minus);
        }
    } else {
        return result;
    }
    return formatted;
}
```

The code will not enter in the first `if` statement, hence will go in the `else` (I saw that wile debugging).

But it'll return `2882303761517117440000001`, adding a `'1'` at the very end of result.

However, when I comment the `malloc()` line (fifth line in this example), the returned value is `288230376151711744000000`, which is the input'd value and logical return.

Any help on this?

Thanks,

**EDIT:**
Putting `printf("%s\n", result)` at the 3rd line and at the 19th actually ""fixes"" (not the quotes, I know it's not a real fix) the problem. Why?

Comment: Also, it returns `NULL` on failure. You might want to check for that instead of assuming and having a segmentation fault without any good explanation.

Comment: You should change the order of the checks in `result[1] == base_0 && result[0] == minus`. Currently you have an out-of-bound access for `rmv_zeros("", '0', '-')`

Comment: Sourav Ghosh: Explain your point. If I ask that it's clearly because I don't understand something and you're not helping.


iharob: I have actually a checker function but I choose to replace it by malloc so my code understanding is easier.


Werner: Thanks for this, implementing it now.

Comment: Your `return formatted` is never reached. You can check that in a debugger (and simply by looking at your code).

Comment: the `malloc` cannot corrupt a literal string. The call to function is exactly as you posted?

Comment: @WernerHenze OP knows it....

Comment: @LPs: The call is not *exactly* like that; result is calculated and alloc'd dynamically. But at the end of the day, this is the exact value of result.

Comment: That means it isn't a literal string, but something dynamically allocated. So, if you put `printf(%s\n", result);` at the top of function and before the `return result`, the output will be different. Am I correct?

Comment: @LPs : 100% correct sir.

Comment: There are no reason for such a behavior of `malloc`. What is your platform?

Comment: @LPs: A custom OS made by my company based on OpenSUSE 13. Oh and I'm fully aware of memleaks, I have yet to fix 'em.

Comment: BTW take note that you are leaking a lot of memory. The `malloc`ated memory at the top is not freed if `return result` is reached.

Comment: OK some news tests revealed that with a printf at the top of the function and one before the `return result;` fixed the problem. However removing the first printf stop fixing the problem. That makes absolutely 0 sense tbh.

Comment: @Greg01re If adding `printf()`s make a problem go away, that is not the same as "fixing" it. Not at all. It does point at a buffer overflow, though.

Comment: @unwind: Aaaand how would I go about fixing that? I'm a beginner with C. (I bet you already guessed from my code, though).

Comment: Play with the code. What happens when you remove all past `malloc` and replace it with `return result`? Also, try setting a watch on the last byte  ("on change" breakpoint) - that should show who is changing it

Comment: You should show the real code calling the function. There is no way the posted code can behave like described. The bug is probably in the code calling this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one reason for such a behavior: [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

One main reason can be the leakage of memory you have with `malloc` into your function. The allocated memory is not `free`d if the returned memory is not returned by function, in other words if the `return result` is reached, as in your test case.

So first of all manage it, otherwise, after some time of execution, `malloc` can fail.

If all parts of your code does not take care of `malloc` return value, as shown in your code, the pointer passed to result can be invalid (in other words `== NULL`)

Into your function you can simply manage the `malloc` as below, but remember that the caller must menage the free of the allocated memory.

```
char* rmv_zeros(char *result, char base_0, char minus)
{
      char* formatted = NULL;

      if (result[0] == base_0 || (result[1] == base_0 && result[0] == minus))
      {
          formatted = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(result) + 1));
          if (formatted != NULL)
          {
             if (if_rmv_zeros_needed(result, formatted, base_0, minus) == char_to_str(base_0))
               {
                  return char_to_str(base_0);
               }
               else
               {
                  return if_rmv_zeros_needed(result, formatted, base_0, minus);
               }
            }
        }
      else
      {
         return result;
      }
      return formatted;
}
```

Take a look at your whole code to catch other similar problems.

Comment: That worked. Thanks mate. And I also removed the `return formatted;` at the very last line because it will, indeed, never be reached.

Comment: Downvote because your answer only adds a NULL pointer check which would not change anything in the cases that the questioner describes. And it ignores the other problems I already commented on. Your answer should be a comment or be improved.

Comment: @WernerHenze I disagree.I moved the `malloc` inside the _main if_, that is the key point here. My answer show OP that he/she have to check and manage **memory leaks** and **have to** check the return of `malloc`. A comment cannot be clear as the posted code. My personal opinion.

Comment: How can memory leaks result in UB?

Comment: @4386427 Can be the causes if at a certain point heap is full and `malloc` continuously fails. So if the code doesn't check the `malloc` return value the behavior can be undefined.

Comment: So it is **not** memory leaks that cause UB. It's a lack of check of the value returned by `malloc`. In this question `formatted` wasn't even used so it can't cause UB. The real problem is most like in the code calling the function.

Comment: @4386427 Yes and no. I think this function continuously leaks memory and after some time the caller, that `malloc` the string passed to `result` pointer, returns `NULL` that isn't checked by the code. So The memory leak causes the failing of `malloc` that causes the Undefined Behavior.

Comment: You are missing my point. I fully agree that this code has bugs which should be fixed. But your answer is wrong - memory leaks will not cause UB. It may drain the system from memory but as long as no one dereference a `NULL` pointer is won't be UB. Just an out of memory. Further there is no way this can explain the problem described by OP. Still the answer is helpful though :-)

Comment: @4386427 I see your point and I edited. Hope my bad English is clear enough.

Comment: `(result[1] == base_0 && result[0] == minus)` should be tested in the proper order: `(result[0] == minus && result[1] == base_0)` to avoid reading `result[1]` if `result[0]` is the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

variable(char *) whose value is changing you can allocate it memory using calloc function because calloc will give contiguous block of memory and now if you use malloc, it will not give the already allocated addresses.